# bMessage format for bluetooth type SMS_GSM using org.bluez.obex IF

Tags: bluetooth, sms

I am trying to use org.bluez.obex interfaces to send sms messages via a Bluetooth connected phone. To do this I used the following piece of code:

```
import dbus
BUS_NAME='org.bluez.obex'
MESSAGE_ACCESS_INTERFACE = 'org.bluez.obex.MessageAccess1'

print("Creating Session")
session_path = client.CreateSession('DC:EE:06:FF:43:D6', { "Target": "map" })
#get the SessionBus instance
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
obj = bus.get_object(BUS_NAME, session_path)
#get MessageAccessInterface
map = dbus.Interface(obj, MESSAGE_ACCESS_INTERFACE)

if map:
    map.PushMessage(<filename>, 'telecom/msg/outbox', dict(), 
reply_handler=reply, error_handler=errors)

def errors(err):
    print (err)

def reply(path, properties):
    print (path)
    print (peoperties)
```

The <**filename**>, according to the very little specs docs I found has bMessage format([doc](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/obex-api.txt?h=5.50)), but I did not find any example of how to create this bMessage.

 I found a template [here](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=429120) on page 19, but did not help, it's too abstract.

Does anybody worked with this and knows how to create a bMessage?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look in obexd/plugins/messages.h and https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5724.txt